# Importing Angular Material in Stackblitz

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have imported **material(7.2.1)** in my **stackblitz** link,

> Still I am unable see the exact UI of material

I have tried to figure out, but no result. Here the **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-xzcwff?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** which i have created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Angular Material lets you know what the issue is in the console:

> Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components
>   may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide:
>   https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

You are not importing a core theme from Angular Material. Add this line to your styles.css:

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

See [this](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) link in the official documentation.